# Licensing of machine learning tool trained on open data

Tags: machine-learning, licensing, corpora, classification

The broad question is: how are the licensing terms for a classifier that is 
trained with open annotated (or manually annotated) data?

1. I am trying to train a dependency parser for German text with annotated data which is licensed under creative commons license (Attribution CC-BY). 
   To train the classifier I want to a use machine learning tool that is licensed under the Apache license. Is it legally permissible to license the 
   resulting classifier (my code and the model file) under a commercial license?
2. Suppose I scrape a text from the web, or alternatively I download a corpus collection that is licensed under Attribution CC-BY, and I use an annotation tool that is open source under the Apache license, and I train a classifier with an Apache machine learning software, will it legally be  permissible to license the resulting classifier under commercial terms?